# String to Long NumberFormatException

Tags: java

I am getting an error while trying to convert a string to Long.

```
Long l = Long.parseLong(str);
```

Exception is:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "20120828000040464018674B"
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:415)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:461)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Javadoc for Long, [`Long.MAX_Value`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#MAX_VALUE) is defined as *2^63 - 1*. The value that you've provided is greater than the given value and hence a *NumberFormatException* is getting thrown.

Answer (score 2):

That number is too large to represent as a `long` in Java. The largest possible `long` is `9223372036854775807L`. Use `BigDecimal` instead.

Also, the last character is the letter `B`, which is invalid in any number.

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a date/time rather than a number

```
String dt = "20120828000040464018674B";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
Date date = sdf.parse(dt.substring(0, 17));
int nanos = Integer.parseInt(dt.substring(17, 17 + 6));
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
System.out.printf("%s%06d%n", sdf2.format(date), nanos);
```

prints

```
2012/08/28 00:00:40.464018674
```

Answer (score 0):

```
20120828000040464018674B
```

Is not a long literal (B at the end)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(Long.MAX_VALUE);
// prints 9223372036854775807
// yours' 20120828000040464018674B
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you go for BigInteger class